# What's this creature on the Canadian Space Agency coat of arms, and why is it there?

Tags: insignia, space-agencies

The [Canadian Space Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_Space_Agency) has a coat of arms with the following creature on it. **What is this creature, and why is it there?**

[image: CSA coat of arms]
A1 Aardvark / CC BY-SA (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)

Comment: It's Canadian Space Agency's Patronus.

Comment: The Governor General of Canada's coat of arms features a space helmet and an MOD sigma. https://www.gg.ca/en/governor-general/governor-general-julie-payette/coat-arms

Comment: What did you think the Canadarm was designed to lift?

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Which makes sense, as she *was* an astronaut.

Comment: @DrSheldon I worked with her quite a bit. I figure that's my "in" if I need to escape northwards.

Comment: Could it be that an extended form of the motto reads SPATIUM FINIS ULTIMUS. HAE NAVIGATIONES INCEPTA NAVIS SUNT ...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's not a unicorn, but a [pantheon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantheon_(mythical_creature)):

> The Pantheon is a mythical or imaginary creature used in heraldry, particularly in Britain. They are often depicted as white deer with the tail of a fox and spangeled with purple stars along their back.

They first became popular in heraldry in the 16th century, but had a comeback in technical and engineering fields in the 20th:

> Examples are the arms of the United Kingdom Atomic Energy Authority, granted in 1955; two pantheons also appear as the supporters of the arms of the Engineering Council (the United Kingdom regulatory body for the engineering profession), granted in 1984.

I think someone thought a beast with stars on it would be appropriate for a space agency.

The formal definition, or blazon, [of the coat of arms is](https://reg.gg.ca/heraldry/pub-reg/project-pic.asp?lang=e&ProjectID=1523&ProjectElementID=5109)

> **Arms**
> Per chevron in chief Bleu céleste semé of estoiles Or and in base Argent a maple leaf its stem issuant from base Gules and voided of a broad arrow point upwards charged at its tip with a torteau;
>
> **Crest**
> *A demi pantheon Azure unguled Gules semé of estoiles Or* bearing between its forelegs a staff Or flying therefrom a streamer paly Bleu céleste and Or as an auroran arc;
>
> **Motto**
> AD FINEM ULTIMUM. This Latin phrase means "To the ultimate end".

"*Demi pantheon Azure unguled Gules semé of estoiles Or*," in the quasi-French language of heraldry, means "a half pantheon, in blue, with red hooves, sown with gold stars."

Comment: I always find it weird to read blazons — all the older terms from the French and the word order make me feel like it's switching back & forth between languages.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert it isn't? It's like reading patents, where the sentences (102) are formed like sentences (102) which prevent readers from reading sentences (102) in a humanly readable manner (709), especially unskilled humans (2) should be able to not read the meaning of the original sentence (301) because the sentence (401) never stops being a sentence (101).

Answer (score 11):

Unicorns have........horns. There's no horn.
That's not a unicorn. It's a [Theow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theow), a wolf with a hooved legs used in heraldry

Comment: The image in the question looks like a theow, but one can't always trust the user contributed copyright free images in wikipedia.

Comment: @JCRM it's the same image as in the WIkipedia page for CSA, although that's presumably under the same constraints. CSA's website doesn't show the CoA, although I only searched briefly.

Comment: if you check the link to the Canadian Governor General's Heraldry Registry in Russel Borogrove's answer, @Barmar, it's more clearly a dear head, and a bushier fox-tail

Comment: @JCRM Took me a while to notice that "is" is a link.